# conditional jump and flag bit in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I'm studying assembly language. I understand that `CMP R1 R2` operation sets flag bits(Carry, Overflow, Zero, Sign etc..)according to the result of R1-R2.
And I understand that conditional jump instructions JXs such as JA, JBE follows after CMP. If flag bit condition is matched, JX instruction make IP jump to specified address.

What I never undetstand is "Tested Conditions" in the picture I attached.

[image]

CMP R1 R2

JAE somewhere

Above code obviously jump to somewhere if R1 is bigger or equal to R2. If R1=0111 and R2=0110, a JAE jump to somewhere. In this case,

`R1-R2 = 0111-0110 = 0111+1010 = 10001 = 0001 with carry bit set`

note that I added 2's complement of 0110 instead of subtracting 0110 because microcontrollers calculate in this way as I know

But textbook says that the JAE will jump if Carry flag is 0. My calculation show that C=1 if R1 is bigger than R2. Another examples show that C=1 if R1 is bigger than R2. There's no issue with sign.

So what's wrong with "tested conditions"?

Comment: Nothing.  If R1 is greater than or equal to R2 there will be no need to borrow when subtracting R2 from R1, so the carry bit is clear.

Comment: Why do you calculate 111-110 by using addition and negating the second argument, and deduct the flags state from that addition? The CF & other flags are relevant to the subtraction, doesn't matter if internally it is done by addition of negated value, and 111-110 is 1 with CF=0, ZF=0, PF=0, etc...

Comment: @Ped7g As I know,there is no subtractor in microprocessor. So it takes 2's complement and add it by adder.

Comment: Subtraction is not the same as addition of 2's complement, because the resulting flags are different as you saw.

Comment: @hskim unfortunately I didn't study 8086 or later x86 CPUs schematics, so I don't know whether they have only adder, but if they do, there must be some kind of subtractor "wrapper" around it to fix flags after the addition to be set as the `sub` instruction defines them. I can just assure you the flags are relevant to the subtraction, i.e. CF = did_borrow and 111-110 doesn't need to borrow -> CF=0. No idea about how it is implemented in transistors.

Comment: When using `jae` you're looking at numbers as unsigned. So adding the 2's complement of a number is not the equivalent as subtracting the original number. That is why the flag results are different. In your example 7 - 6 is not the same as 7 + 10 (it's 10, not "-6").

Comment: subtraction is implemented in logic as addition with the second operand inverted and the carry in to the lsb inverted.  whether or not the carry out of the msbit is inverted and called a borrow depends on the architecture design some do that some dont.  All the flags can be properly resolved.  a = b + c = b + (-c) identity has been true in math long before electricity much less transistors much less binary logic much less twos complement.

Comment: The tested condition column describes what the logic does, better documentation makes it clear when a jump if greater means signed or unsigned as the flags matter, it also matters whether or not the carry is inverted into a borrow on the way out of a subtraction (addition with a negative).  Best of course to have good documentation ,which this clearly isnt, but at least it shows the tested conditions so that you can do some experiments on the logic to see how the flags work, then us jump if carry or jump if not carry on your own for less than or greater than (or with equal)....

Comment: rather than many of these combinations that you dont really need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This subtraction

```
R1-R2 = 0111-0110
```

gets implemented like this in logic

```
     1
  0111
+ 1001
========
```

finish the math

```
 11111
  0111
+ 1001
========
  0001
```

so carry out (unsigned overflow) is a 1, signed overflow is a 0 as the carry in and carry out to the msbit match  can also determine this from the msbits of the operands and the result.  if the msbits of the operands match each other but the msbit of the result doesnt match the msbits then signed overflow.

not zero so a z flag would be 0, and the msbit is not set so an n flag would not be set.

the next question is does this architecture invert carry out into the carry flag on a subtract making it a borrow or do they take it straight across?

In any case you have your four basic flags, carry, signed overflow, negative and zero.  With good documentation you get a list of flags for the condition.  You kind of know in your head if you want a greater than or less than or whatever, this little pencil and paper test, along with doing it on the processor and dumping the flags to see if this architecture inverts the carry out, also reading the docs to see if all the flags are touched by the test instruction in question, then looking at the various tested conditions to see which ones match your result.